# How to center an icon inside a material card

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am just new to css and to angular material ,I wanted to ask help how we can center the icon on the card based on the the design from figma , I tried copying the css from figma but it does not center the icon based on the design. Does anyone know techniques to center the icon ? does it need flex layout ? why is that the css from figma when I implement it to css and html is not the same ? I just copy pasted it from figma. Thanks for any help.

The EG icon on the image below is that I want to put in center inside the material card.

**My Current CSS**

```
.custom.mat-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 16px 16px 32px;
  position: static;
  width: 448px;
  height: 527px;
  margin-left: 142px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.name-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;

  position: static;
  left: 28.81%;
  right: 28.81%;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 49.21%;
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}
```

**My Current HTML Code**

```
 <div>
      <mat-card class="custom">
           <app-user-profile-icon class="icon" 
                *ngIf="this.data.firstName && this.data.lastName" 
                [firstName]="this.data.firstName"
                [lastName]="this.data.lastName"
                [size]="32"
                style="padding-right: 8px;">
           </app-user-profile-icon>
      </mat-card>
 </div>
```

**Figma Design**
[image: The Figma Design]

**CSS from Figma Design**

[image: CSS from Figma]

Comment: Does `.name-icon` exist? It's in your CSS but no element in your HTML has that class name. I see there is a `class="icon"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O :)

You want `align-items: center` instead of `align-items: flex-start`.

```css
.custom.mat-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;           /*  This  */
  /* align-items: flex-start; */ /*  Instead of this */
  padding: 16px 16px 32px;
  position: static;
  width: 448px;
  height: 527px;
  margin-left: 142px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

And here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4fq5ts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcenter-mat-card%2Fcenter-mat-card.component.css) of it in action.